# Is there any way to detect likely missing '@' signs in Razor views?

Tags: c#, .net, razor

Missing an `@` sign in a Razor view will cause the text to be displayed as-is.  For a human eye this result is clearly wrong (unless you're running a site where people come to read about C#).  Is there any static analysis tool that will help catch likely instances of this?  I.e. C# code blocks that are not prepended with `@`.

Example: (this is lacking `@`, I'd like some static analysis to flag this in a Razor view)

```
if (value != null)
{       
    <text>We have a value.</text>           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One such tool is the Razor Analyzer, which is included in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language NuGet package. The Razor Analyzer is a C#-based static analysis tool that is designed to help detect issues with Razor views at compile-time.

And this is how you can add razor analyzer in your project

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language" Version="x.x.x" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="RazorCompile" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="dotnet razor /p:RazorAnalyzersEnabled=true" />
</Target>
```

Please refer to this might be helpful- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40638